# Is there a way to assign a quoted string to a var without escaping?

Tags: linux, bash

I don't want to escape the single quote below:

```
a='I'm a $coder.'
```

Is there a trick to do that?

Comment: If you don't want to escape the single quote, you would use double quotes, but then you need to escape the dollar sign. If you accept escaping the single quote, you can do `a='I'\''m a $coder.'`

Comment: have a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: *Why* don't you want to escape the single quote? The simplest solutions are `a=$'I\'m a $coder'` and `a="I'm a \$coder"`. *Something* need to be escaped, unless you're OK with using multiple types of quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid all forms of quoting and escaping using a here document:

```
IFS= read -rd '' a << "END"
I'm a $coder, hear me roar: ~!@#$%^&*()+"]',/
END
```

Comment: It is very useful. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
 a="I'm a "'$coder.'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes (without needing to escape):

```
a="'I'm a $coder.'"
```

Comment: But here `$coder` will be interpreted as a variable. It is not clear if this is desired.

Comment: You can escape the dollar sign (although it's not clear why that would be acceptable when escaping the single quote was not; you've also unnecessarily added single quotes as data.

Comment: It's not really clear whether OP wanted to include single quotes in the string or expand the variable "coder"/want to keep `$coder` literally. So, saying/downvoting one is better than other seems premature.

Answer (score 0):

A two step solution:

```
$ b='$coder'
$ a="I'm a $b"

$ echo "$a"
I'm a $coder
```